# What does this SQL query with MIN() in HAVING clause do exactly?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL and I have the following table *employees*: [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDnjk.png).

I had an exercise in which I had to select the oldest person. I know the correct way to do that is with a subquery: `SELECT name, dob FROM employees WHERE dob = (SELECT MIN(dob) FROM employees)`.

However, I did it like so: `SELECT name, dob FROM employees HAVING dob = MIN(dob)`. Now this returns an empty set, but doesn't throw any errors. So what does it do exactly? I've read that MySQL allows to refer to columns from SELECT clause in HAVING clause, without any GROUP BY clause. But why does it return an empty set?

Comment: The second query produces wrong results. Using `HAVING` without `GROUP BY` is not valid according to the SQL Standard. MySQL 5.x used to accept these queries, but fortunately they are disabled by default in MySQL 8.x.

Comment: @TheImpaler I think you are confusing two different things; this is not allowed with `only_full_group_by` which is now the default, but that has nothing to do with `having` without a `group by`

Comment: Actually, "IWD 9075-2:201?(E) Foundation document" Section: _7.10 <having clause>_ ... _1) Let HC be the <having clause>. Let TE be the <table expression> that immediately contains HC. If TE does not immediately contain a <group by clause>, then “GROUP BY ()” is implicit._  .. Notice, without an explicit <group by clause>, `GROUP BY ()` is implied.  So we can have `HAVING` without an explicit `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Your version of MySQL does not support or is not configured to recognize the functional dependence issue, where `dob` in the _<having clause>_ is not functionally dependent on the `GROUP BY` terms.  In this case, `GROUP BY ()` is implied.  Your version of MySQL does allow the form, but the result isn't guaranteed to behave rationally.  The `dob` it chose to use (of all the available `dob`s) simply didn't match `MIN(dob)` for the group, returning no rows.

Comment: @JonArmstrong "So we can have HAVING without an explicit GROUP BY" -- yes, but this is clearly not the case; in the case you describe (note the **parenthesis** in the implicit `GROUP BY ()`) all select expressions must be aggregated or be literals. The OP is trying to produce two non-aggregated, non-literal expresions (`name` and `dob`). This doesn't make sense nor is legal.

Comment: @TheImpaler Agreed. Absolutely.  The poster has other issues too.  I was just making the one point about HAVING without GROUP BY and then went on to explain those issues as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use MAX (or other aggregate functions) in the select columns or the having clause, you cause an implicit `GROUP BY ()` (that is, all rows are grouped together into a single result row).

And when grouping (whether all rows or with a specific `GROUP BY`), if you specify a column outside of an aggregate function (such as your `dob =`) that is not one of the things being aggregated on or something functionally dependent on it (for example, some other column in a table when you are grouping by the primary key for that table), one of two things will happen:

If you have enabled the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY sql_mode (which is the default in newer versions), you will receive an error:

> In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression ... contains nonaggregated column '...'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

If you have not enabled ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, a value from some arbitrary one of the grouped rows will be used.  So it is possible your `dob = MIN(dob)` will be true (and it will definitely be true if all rows have the same dob), but you can't rely on it doing anything useful and should avoid doing this.